# How to define a value in binary bit way in C++?

Tags: c++, literals

It is hard to describe what my question is. Basically I just want to define a value in binary way:

For example in Hex I can define a value like this:

```
BYTE data = 0XAB;
```

the way I want to define it is like this:

```
BYTE data = 0B10101011;
```

As far as I know C or C++ doesn't support **0B**.
The way I do this is I use different bit for different meaning, if the value is define in this it is much easier for me to know what the value means right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[C++14 allows binary literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Binary_literals) with the `0b` or `0B` prefix:

```
BYTE data = 0B10101011;
```

(See under "2.14.2 Integer literals" in the language specification)

Comment: These are supported as far back as clang 2.9, gcc 4.9, and intel's C++ compiler v14. Visual Studio 2015 will add support for binary literals. Sources: [(1)](http://www.italiancpp.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/CppISO-Feb2014-r1.pdf) [(2)](http://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-preview-vs#C++)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have support for C++14, you can do

```
BYTE data = std::bitset<8>("10101011").to_ulong(); // casted back to BYTE
```

Answer (score 1):

Some recent versions of C/C++ support this feature. You can use a bitset instead if the feature is not available.

```
bitset<8> b(string("01010101"));
```

bitset offers some conversion functions too, so these can be used to get a number.

Comment: No. No version of C supports this (not even the latest C11) and only one version of C++ (The latest C++14)